# triggering a function onload replacing a blur()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am using a function called LoadCoordinates. My first thougt was i need to read this onload.. but after trying a lot of different codes, i cant..

This is how its triggered normally

```
$("#address1").blur(function()
        {
            loadCoordinates("");
        });
```

The problem is to "run" this i have to click the input and then clic the body (so address1 lost focus and blur is triggered)

I have tried to load this on page load using seveeral different codes like

```
$(loadCoordinates(""));
```

or this

```
$(function(){
  loadCoordinates();
  $("#address1").blur( loadCoordinates );
});
```

This is not working, i think it has to do something because my select lists are using "SELECT BOX IT" http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/

Anyway..

How can i make or trigger the same as is triggering "blur()" on the address1 input.. but when the page is ready. and after selectbox it has loaded  & builded the lists with options..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will trigger `blur`. You need to make sure you do this before applying any plugin to the element, or have to use the API of the plugin to affect and changes

```
 $("#address1").blur( loadCoordinates ).blur();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQQP3/)

Comment: Thanks so much, could the plugin selectbox it affect this.. beacuse even after triggered, some values for the select lists, are missing... but not in the blur.. when i click in the input and then lost focus work like charm gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js

Comment: question says you have `input` but plugin works on `<select>`...am confused

Comment: Yes the input triggers the function.. but the functions itself takes some values for some select boxes around.. this values are missing actually.

Comment: ahhh are you using the API of plugin to get the values? Usually have to do that. Your original select has been modified

Comment: i suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net that displays what you are trying to do

Comment: HOpe i can , there are some variables coming from PHP , but i will try to build one fiddle, thanks.